How to fix default import with TypeScript's NodeNext resolution?
I am authoring a component library that relies on icons from @spectrum-icons/workflow package. The library will be used in SSR workflows as well so, I am using more stricter settings for TypeScript configuration:
{
  "module": "NodeNext",
  "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
}

This setting forces me to have proper extension for imported files which is compatible with Node.js runtime during server-side rendering. However, when I try to import any icon from the @spectrum-icons/workflow then it causes a TypeScript error:
import Contrast from '@spectrum-icons/workflow/Contrast';

export function AppHeader(_props: AppHeaderProps) {
  return (
    <Header>
      <ActionButton>
        {/* Error : 'Contrast' cannot be used as a JSX component. */}
        <Contrast />
      </ActionButton>
    </Header>
  );
}

The above code works fine at runtime as the @spectrum-icons/workflow/Contrast has proper default export:
// Type definition
// node_modules/@spectrum-icons/workflow/Contrast.d.ts

import { IconPropsWithoutChildren } from '@react-spectrum/icon';
import React from 'react';
export default function Contrast(props: IconPropsWithoutChildren): React.JSX.Element;

// ESM MJS file
// node_modules/@spectrum-icons/workflow/Contrast.module.mjs
import { Icon } from '@react-spectrum/icon';
import React from 'react';

export default function Contrast(props) {
  return React.createElement(Icon, props);
}

However, if I use explicit default import as shown below, then TypeScript error goes away; but as obvious, it fails at runtime:
import Contrast from '@spectrum-icons/workflow/Contrast';

export function AppHeader(_props: AppHeaderProps) {
  //  This works with TypeScript
  const Contrast2 = Contrast.default;

  return (
    <Header>
      <ActionButton>
        {/* Works here but fails at runtime */}
        <Contrast2 />
      </ActionButton>
    </Header>
  );
}

What's the proper way to fix this and make this work with TypeScript's NodeNext + NodeNext configuration?
